# What do the different levels of the magic item quicken spell rod do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I am using http://www.d20pfsrd.com for most of my pathfinder rules but it's entry on rods has three tiers but it does not clarify what the different tiers do.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-quicken

What is the difference between minor, normal and greater quicken metamagic rods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excerpt from [Metamagic Rods](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods) in overall:

> **Lesser and Greater Metamagic rods:** Normal metamagic rods can be used with spells of 6th level or lower. Lesser rods can be used with spells of 3rd level or lower, while greater rods can be used with spells of 9th level or lower.

Thus, you can quicken 3rd or lower spell with lesser, 6th or lower with normal, and 9th or lower with greater. You use the level **before** adjustment from the rod's metamagic. (So, if you are only using metamagic from the rod's power, spell level does not change.)

> Metamagic rods hold the essence of a metamagic feat, allowing the user to apply metamagic effects to spells (but not spell-like abilities) as they are cast. This does not change the spell slot of the altered spell.